# How to display getdata from mongodb using amcharts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, amcharts

I'm new to mean-stack and I'm trying to display my values from mongodb using amchartsJS, I used api.js to get my data, then controllers to pass the variable to my html. My table is working properly and displays the values from mongodb, but how can I implement this to chartsJS?

**So I tried this inside my html**

```
<script>

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [ {
  "donor": "{{person.donors_name}}",
  "count": 501.9
  } ],
  "valueField": "count",
  "titleField": "donor",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
</script>
```

But the results give me `{{person.donors_name}}`

[image]

Here my code for getting the values:

**api.js**

```
router.get('/blooddonationmanagement', function(req, res) {

    Blooddonation.find({},function(err, blooddonations) {
        res.json({ success: true, blooddonations: blooddonations });
    });   
});
```

**blooddonationCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('blooddonationControllers', [])
.controller('blooddonationCtrl', function(Blooddonation,$scope) {
    var app = this;
    function getBlooddonations() {

        Blooddonation.getUsers().then(function(data) {    
            app.blooddonations = data.data.blooddonations;  
    });
}
```

**table.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in blooddonationmanagement.blooddonations">
    <td>{{ person.donation_no }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.donors_name }}</td>    
</tr>
```

I already tried this using php, and works using mysqldb but I dont know how to do this in mean-stack:

```
"dataProvider": 
  [
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>

    {
      "TRENDX": "<?php echo $row['trendx'] ?>",
      "Values": <?php echo $row['counter']; ?>
    },

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  ]
```

Comment: There are multiple charts right?, Could you please share more HTML how you are getting all those charts

Comment: what do you mean by multiple charts, I used amchartsJS version 3 for this then to display the chart div I just used <div id="chartdiv"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize chart from your controller, modify dataProvider properties as per your need :

```js
angular.module('blooddonationControllers', [])
    .controller('blooddonationCtrl', function(Blooddonation,$scope) {
        var app = this;

        function getBlooddonations() {
            Blooddonation.getUsers()
                .then(function(data) {
                    app.blooddonations = data.data.blooddonations;

                    initChart();

                    return true
                });
        }

        function initChart() {
            var data_series = [];

            for(let key in app.blooddonations) {
                data_series.push({
                    "donor": app.blooddonations[key].donors_name,
                    "count": 501.9
                });
            }
            
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
                "type": "pie",
                "theme": "none",
                "dataProvider": data_series,
                "valueField": "count",
                "titleField": "donor",
                "balloon":{
                    "fixedPosition":true
                },
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using it as angular expression. you can directly access the value in Amchart config like:

```
 AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [ {
  "donor": person.donors_name,
  "count": 501.9
  } ],
  "valueField": "count",
  "titleField": "donor",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

Comment: i tried it but it gives me ReferenceError: person is not defined

Comment: my bad, you are accessing person from your model ref blooddonationmanagement.blooddonations, you have to create dataProvider while looping through the app.blooddonations and creating an array of object of {"donor":,"count"} and the same you can use in config

Comment: I'm thinking of this too, but I don't know where to put and where to call it